# Page view for tablet, phone, portrait/landscape

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

I have to create responsive sites that they will fit into fixed resolutions for defined types.

desktop/tablet landscape = 1024px

tablet portrait = 768px

phone landscape = 480px

phone portrait = 320px

is that posible to achieve? I have graphic assets for these resolutions. And I have to make it fit to screen on load. (current resolution and spread it to screen width)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, look into learning media-queries.

Comment: But here is so many resolutions/dpi for tablets/phones and many browsers.. I tried but didnt founded any good solution.

Comment: How do I set different viewport for mobile/tablet  landscape/portrait